# Get only values in brackets after row splitting using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I'm working on a simple awk script: `awk -f file.awk test.txt`. My function:

```
{
split($1, arr, "[()()]")
for (i in arr) {
    print(arr[i])
}
}
```

My test file:

```
1(2)V2(9)
```

I'm getting

```
1
2
V2
9
```

How can I get values only in brackets?

```
2
9
```

A count of values in brackets can be different.

Comment: Start printing from `arr[2]` and increase the index by two for following iterations.

Comment: `awk -F'[()]+' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) $i="" }1' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I have some complex logic inside my awk script. Firstly, I split using space as a separator. And then I use the function above for one specific column. Does it possible to complete this task using split function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get it using `match` function:

```
awk '{s=$1; while (match(s, /\([^)]*\)/ )) {
  print substr(s, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2); s=substr(s, RSTART+1)}}' <<< "1(2)V2(9)"
```

```
2
9
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='[(][^)]+)' -F'[()]' '$0=RT{print $2}' file
2
9
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk you can use `FPAT` (*field pattern*) to specify how a field looks like, rather than being limited to specify a delimiter. That's handy in this case:

```
echo "1(2)V2(9)" | \
    gawk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/[()]/,"",$i);print $i}}' FPAT="[(][^)]+[)]"
2
9
```

See: [Defining fields by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)